# Jquery Ajax Submit a form when i click a button which not been in the form

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, jquery

I have this code:

```
$(document).on('submit','#roomsend',function(e) {
   var form = $('#roomsend');
   var data = form.serialize();
   $.post('php/roomlist.php', data, function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      $('#power').replaceWith(response);
   });
   return false;
});
```

This works with a  Submit button inside the form. But now I have a button outside the form:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" id="roomsendbutton"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Save</button>
```

How must I must be the code, that when i clicked the button the button all actions will be work and the form submits?

Comment: $(document).on('click','#roomsendbutton',function(e){..}) solves your problem i guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using HTML5, you can use the new form attribute:

```
<button form="roomsend" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="roomsendbutton"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Save</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sEHLf/

Should probably look up browser support for it though.

Comment: If only it were supported more broadly. It appears as though IE10 doesn't support it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.trigger()` method:

```
$('#roomsendbutton').on('click', function () {
    $('#roomsend').trigger('submit');
});
```

---

References:

- [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) - jQuery API Documentation

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work. I want also no submit button in the form but only these who is outside the form .

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like this in your jQuery..

```
$('#roomsendbutton').click(function(){
     $(your form name).trigger('submit');

});
```

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work. I want also no submit button in the form but only these who is outside the form .

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click','#roomsendbutton',function(e) {
   var form = $('#roomsend');
   var data = form.serialize();
   $.post('php/roomlist.php', data, function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      $('#power').replaceWith(response);
   });
   return false;
});
```

Just bind the click event on the button.

Comment: But then the form will submit without hitting this handler when the user presses enter on a form input.

Comment: Well if the button is out of the form, pressing enter won't do anything. And nothing prevents you from binding both event if needed ;)

Comment: If the button is not in the form, and the input is, pressing enter on the input will submit the form. But yes, you could bind additional events to fix that too.